# How to I change the column width on Laravel Jetstream Register page

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I have added an Option Field in my Jetstream Registration page. The functionality is fine. I just want to change the column width of this field to match the other fields.

```
<div class="mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <x-jet-label for="registeras" value="{{ ('Register As') }}" />
        <select class="form-control" name="registeras" id="registeras">
            <option value="one">Option 1</option>
            <option value="two">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the same classes that jetstream uses to your select element which is most probably `class="block mt-1 w-full"`

So your code should be:

```
<div class="mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <x-jet-label for="registeras" value="{{ ('Register As') }}" />
        <select class="form-control block mt-1 w-full" name="registeras" id="registeras">
            <option value="one">Option 1</option>
            <option value="two">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```